# KMeans Clustering - use created clusters in SVM

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, k-means

I'm using KMeans clustering to split data into 2 clusters as follows.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import cluster
##################################################

# load data
clm = np.genfromtxt('data.csv',delimiter=',', skiprows=1)
X = clm[:,(1,12)].astype(float)

# define kmeans learner, then fit with data
kmeans = cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=2)
kmeans.fit(X)

# define centroids
centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
labels = kmeans.labels_

#print(centroids)
#print(labels)

#set color
colors = ["g.", "r."]

for i in range(len(X)):
    print("coordinate:",X[i], "label:", labels[i])
    plt.plot(X[i][0], X[i][1], colors[labels[i]], markersize= 10)


# plot
plt.scatter(centroids[:,0], centroids[:,1], marker = "x", s=150, linewidth = 5, zorder=10)
plt.xlabel('Read proportion')
plt.ylabel('Memory_used_Read')
plt.xlim(0,100)
plt.ylim(ymin=0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

In KMeans clustering, there is no labeled data for set S=(x,y) while in SVM for set S input x and target data y. What I'm up to do is to use created  clusters separately in SVM. I'm not sure how to get X,y for each cluster. Please let me know if you have any suggestion.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not 100% clear what you're trying to do. If you want to use the cluster-assignment as class label you get y from `y = kmeans.predict(X)`. The features X are the same. Use them in the SVM like this:

```
y = kmeans.predict(X)

svm = SVM()
svm.fit(X, y)
```